# How to get the Prototype of Bean in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA. I have created one entity as a Spring bean with prototype scope. How to I get the bean for each object to persist in database?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="sample")
@Scope(value=ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class Sample {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

If I don't use the entity as Spring bean then I will use the following code to get the object:

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
```

How should I use the object using the Prototype scope bean in Spring Boot?

Comment: The fact that you use Spring doesn't mean everything has to be a spring bean. There is nothing wrong with creating a new instance yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to define scope for entity. Entities are not like spring bean.

Spring data uses three important components for persisting into the database.

1) Entity Class - Each table has to be defined its own java object model called entity class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="sample")
public class Sample {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name") //Column name from the table
    private String name;
```

2) Repo Interface- In Which you can define own implementation of SQL, and it would have save method by default.

```
public interface SampleRepo extends CrudRepository<Sample,Long>{
List<Sample> findByName(String name);
}
```

3) Client program:

```
private SampleRepo s;
//instantiate s using autowired setter/constructor
....
//Select example
List<Sample> sampleList=s.findByName("example");

//Insert example
//Id is auto. So no need to setup explicit value for it. 
Sample entity=new Sample();
s.setName("Example");
s.save(entity);
```